# Replace relative urls in html by absolute urls

Tags: regex, node.js, web-scraping

I'm scraping a external webpage to save in file, but sometimes this file contains relative urls that i can't view because this files not will be found. I want replace by absolute urls. I'm insterested in some module or function that replace all relative urls in html string to absolute. Any idea?

```
var request = require('request');
var WEBSITE = 'http://somewebsite.com/';
request.get(WEBSITE, function(error, response, body){
    body = replace_all_relative_by_absolute(body);
    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: A web application should be almost entirely ignorant as to the domain it's running on

Comment: No, maybe you don't understand. I want scrap content, but i need save this html with absolute urls because this stored html file not will be show good when i will open.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the links and add the domain yourself.

Using jQuery, install with:

```
npm install -S 'jquery@>=2.1'
npm install -S 'jsdom@latest'
```

Example implementation (barely tested):

```
var env = require('jsdom').env;

function addDomainToLinks(domain, html, callback) {
  env(html, function (err, window) {
    var $ = require('jquery')(window);
    $.each($('a'), function(i, v) {
      var href = $(v).attr('href');
      // Match links starting with /, but not //
      // You probably want to do handle './', and do the same for images, etc.
      if (href.match(/^\/[^\/]/)) {
        $(v).attr('href', domain + href);
      }
    });
    callback($('html')[0].outerHTML);
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
addDomainToLinks('http://example.com', html, function(html) {
  console.log(html);
});
```

Comment: this not works. Sometimes have "./", sometimes have "../", "../../", etc... url nodejs module have resolve method that we can use, but i need find ALL absolute and relative urls in all file (html, css, js), maybe with regex.

Comment: @user1710825 yes, that's why I wrote a comment saying that you need to implement that, it's just an example. I don't know of any package that can do that automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

import this

```
    from urlparse import urljoin
```

and then

```
    urljoin(base_url, file_url)
```

Comment: But this it's like url.resolve, i need find all urls (of html, css and js inside), later we can iterate.